# How do I switch from Python 3.5 back to 3.6 on mac terminal

Tags: python

I just dealt with the worse bug in my entire 3 years of computer programming!  It turns out that because I wanted to work with the natural language toolkit I had to install python 3.5 even though I'm using python 3.6.  So I downloaded 3.5 and now my terminal is using python 3.5 by default and I can't get it back to 3.6. Because I was using python 3.5 which does not automatically order dictionaries it was throwing my program off because it relies on ordered dictionaries.  It took me 4 hours to figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) and/or virtualenvwrapper. This is a utility that allows you to use multiple different environments, with different Python versions, different pip packages installed, etc.

To find the 3.5 version, run `which python` in your terminal to find the path to the `python` executable; then look at your `PATH` environment, and see where the location of that Python is on your `PATH`. Then you need to find out where that path is getting added; this will depend on your OS/Shell.

Comment: I want to use the 3.6 version not the 3.5 version.  Also, I really don't know how to use virtualenv.  Also, once I found out the path it's not very clear what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: Yes, I am saying you need to find where the 3.5 version is located, so you can make sure that location is not in your `PATH`. Editing your `PATH` will depend on your environment, e.g. your `.bashrc` on Mac (didn't notice the Mac in your question at first, oops).

Comment: It depends on how your path was edited in the first place; that's a new question, and one that's better suited to SuperUser or ServerFault. Most likely it is in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`; it's hard to say where it is without knowing the output of `which python`, `echo $PATH`, and the contents of your `.bashrc` and/or `.bash_profile`.

Comment: got it.  I opened my bash profile and there it was.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Tough times for sure, sorry to hear that.

I use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage the different python versions on my system. This allows you to create virtual environments using whichever version you want.

EDIT to address comments.

I totally understand that setting up virtualenv or something like pyenv is not simple. However, it is unfortunately the easiest way to deal with (and avoid) situations like this. There are two essential concepts that are important here:

1) Isolation - Virtualenv takes care of this. When you install dependencies in a virtual environment, they will not affect your other environments or system python installation.

2) Multiple Python Versions - In your case, you needed to use a module that did not support 3.6. Instead of creating a virtual environment using python 3.5, you accidentally messed up your system installation of 3.6. Recovering from these types of misconfigurations can be difficult, and it is often easier to simply prevent it in the first place.

Again, I completely understand that this might be complicated, I remember thinking the same thing, but it is less complicated than troubleshooting the misconfigurations that can occur without this tooling.

Comment: pyenv is too complicated for me.  surely, there must be an easier, one line command line  that I can input into terminal